# NodeJs route execution time

Tags: node.js, express, response

every time i do an http request to any route in my app i got in my console the route method , execution time and and anther number that i have no idea what it means(will love to know) .
[image]

does anyone know how can i use this data? i want to record routes that takes more then x time so i can improve those  routes.

i try do find from console. in the express framework as i assumed its coming from there but no luck

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @hurricane i need something global not for a specific route  i have more then a 800 routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see from the screenshot, you're probably using [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) middleware.

By default it logs all the requests in the [dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) format which is -

```
:method :url :status :response-time ms - :res[content-length]
```

So according to your screenshot -

1. *Patch* is the method.
2. */trades/* is the url path.
3. *200* is the status code.
4. *5.893* is the response time.
5. *2* is content length of the response.

I think you were asking about content length. It's basically the size of your response body in bytes.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/master/index.js#L228), Morgan keeps track of the request start / end times by adding instance properties to the request.

The request time looks like it's calculated when the response starts to write headers, as such you would need to follow the same pattern....but only *after* Morgan has been configured e.g.

```
import onHeaders from 'on-headers';
import logger from 'morgan';

app.use(logger()); // configure morgan
app.use((req, res, next) =>
  onHeaders(res, () => {
    console.log(logger['response-time'](req, res)); // this may work 
    // alternatively, use req._startAt / res._startAt to work it out (see source for implementation)
  });
  return next();
)
```

The other alternative of course is just do it yourself with custom middleware, or use something off the shelf like [response-time](https://github.com/expressjs/response-time)